# C# and Html Agility Pack: Null Exception in nested foreach loop

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get each `<li>` text and link value using Html Agility Pack in C# and further I need the value of `<div>` and `<h1>` from the webpage of each `<li>` link **abc.com/one.html**, **abc.com/two.html** & **abc.com/three.html**

I'm getting this error at runtime:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

```cs
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: second]
System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip(IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, Func`3 resultSelector) +2619657
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
    <li>ListOne<a href="abc.com/one.html"></a></li>
    <li>ListTwo<a href="abc.com/two.html"></a></li>
    <li>ListThree<a href="abc.com/three.html"></a></li>  
</ul>
```

**C#**

```cs
string Url = "WebAddress1";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/ul[1]/li").Zip(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/ul[1]/li/a"), (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b }))
{
    var a = item.A;
    var b = item.B;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(a.InnerText);
    ListBox2.Items.Add(b.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));

    string Url2 = "WebAddress1" + b.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
    HtmlWeb web2 = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc2 = web2.Load(Url2);
    foreach (var item2 in doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/article/div[4]/div[1]").Zip(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/article/h1"), (c, d) => new { C = c, D = d }))
    {
        var c = item2.C;
        var d = item2.D;
        ListBox3.Items.Add(c.InnerText);
        ListBox4.Items.Add(d.InnerText);
    }
}
```

*Note: This code works with xPath of some element of the webpage: **abc.com/one.html**, **abc.com/two.html** and **abc.com/three.html**

Comment: Did you try to debug that? The exception says that the parameter of your Zip method is NULL and that is not supported.

Comment: `doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/article/h1")` extracts the `h1` element of the `article` element with your specified `id` and there isn't one.

Comment: If I place the second `foreach` loop out side the first `foreach` loop and provide the same link in `Url2`  then its work. Exception occurs only when I use nested `foreach` loop. 
Also the above nested code work only with xPath of  navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Some of the xPath return null value. So I just increase one more line of code.

```
string Url = "WebAddress1"; 
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); 
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url); 
if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/ul[1‌​]/li") != null && doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"pageContent\"]/ul[1]‌​/li/a") != null)//Added this line 
{ foreach (...) { // } }
```